# How to test which elements in a vector contains string?

Tags: r, string, match, string-matching

How to test which exact element in a vector contains string?

```
line<-c('The sentence which contains words')
f<-c('a', 'set', 'of', 'different', 'words')
```

The desirable result is

```
'words'
```

I tried different variants and all of them don't work appropriately

```
which(paste(c('a', 'set', 'of', 'different', 'words'),collapse="|") %in% line)

grep(paste(c('a', 'set', 'of', 'different', 'words'),collapse="|"),line)
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You may need `stringr::str_extract_all(line, paste0("\\b(", paste(f, collapse="|"), ")\\b"))` or with `gregexpr/regmatches`

Comment: or `intersect(strsplit(line, "\\s+")[[1]], f)`. Similarly, `Map(intersect, strsplit(line, "\\s+"), list(f))` if you have several elements in the `line` vector